# How do I display 2 foreign keys in a view ASP.NET MVC by using LinQ

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 4 tables, 3 of them are used for category and sub category for one item.

**Category**

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }


    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**Product**

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    //Product can have many items
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    //Product can have many brands
    public ICollection<Brand> Brands { get; set; }

}
```

**Brand**

```
public class Brand
{
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    //Brand can have many items.
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**Item.cs**

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Item's Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public bool IsActived { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public bool IsDiscounted { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }  
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Brand")]
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
}
```

Example for the item table:

```
id      name            categoryId   productId   BrandId
---------------------------------------------------------
1       Google Phone        1            1          1
```

Now I want to display name from table Brand in item view. I have tried to use include but it can only display one related table to the view.

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Browse(string name)
{
        var genreModel = db.Products.Include("Items")
            .SingleOrDefault(g => g.Name == name);
        var viewModel = new BrowseViewModel
        {
            Product = genreModel
        };

        return View(viewModel);
}
```

View model:

```
public class BrowseViewModel
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model eStore.ViewModels.BrowseViewModel
@foreach (var item in Model.Product.Items)

<li><img src="/Images/Uploads/items/@item.ItemId/Thumbs/@item.ImagePath" class="img-responsive"></li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Detail", "Shop", new { id = item.ItemId }, null)</li>
<li>@item.Price</li>
<li>@item.Brand.BrandName</li>
```

When I run the project, and browse on item name, I get this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Your sample code is unclear. Please give us more details `BrowseViewModel`, `Product`, `Items` class.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being clear. I just have added code in my post.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow, did you check the Model.Product.Items if returns data to the view, usually this error is due to an empty Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Browse(string name)
    {
        var genreModel = db.Items.Where(x=> x.Name == name).Include(x=>x.Product).Include(x=>x.Brand).FirstOrDefault();
        var viewModel = new BrowseViewModel
        {
            Product = genreModel.Product,
            Item = genreModel ,
            Brand = genreModel.Brand
        };


        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Edit: - explanation
I do both includes to to ensure the navigational properties are not null, then assign them as per your viewmodel.

I would definitely simplify my view model as they may cause some confusion as your `Item` property will have the navigational properties present. ie:

`genreModel.Item.Brand.BrandName`
will be the same as 
`genreModel.Brand.BrandName`

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable EagerLoading and Disabled LazyLoading? 
Table "Item" is Database table or just a plain class ?

I would suggest read about EagerLoading, how does it work?